# Record only the audio track of all the participants in a single file for Twilio Video

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-video

I'm building a web app where two participants join a Twilio video room. I want to set the recordings rules so that at the end I only get only an audio recording that contains the voice from all the participants. Is there a way to configure this via the dashboard or the API?